# Please select a valid device before running the application : VS 2015 and Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to mobile development, a few days ago i install Xamarin and Android SDK. I have just created a blank app and when i try to run it says built was unsuccessful and shows the above message.

But when i open the main.axml i can see Nexus one with android 7.1 is selected. I did change these option but the same error.

I did try everything mentioned here on stackoverflow and on Xamarin but none worked for me. i did update Xamarin and downgrade JDK to 8 from 9 as it was mentioned somewhere on the blog but still i am out of luck. its been more than 5 days i am trying different solutions and finally i have to put it in front of the professionals.

Its just an empty app not even a single line of code.
I can give teamviewer access if necessary.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must install an emulator on which you will run the application. Or connect physical device. There is nothing to do with Xamarin or SDK versions. Your app compiles OK. You just need some device (virtual or physical) to **run** your application.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i think Xamarin have its builtin xamarin player for visual studio and i even downloaded one from microsoft but when i try to install it it says it can be install only on windows 10 or windows server. i tried to find one for windows 7 but i couldn't. so any advise on that? is there any link you know for windows 7? or i can work with the builtin xamarin player?

Comment: Try an emulator wbich comes with the Android sdk. Or just connect your phone via usb.

Comment: thanks again for the reply. after downloading xamarin player on my phone i was able to connect my phone with VS, so when i try to run the app its giving me this error that i searched and tried all those different solutions but none worked for me. the error is : 'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'Main'. and i wonder why just an empty app does not run properly?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95647/resource-layout-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-main

Comment: i am using my phone because i was not able to use any emulator for now.